# jQuery - how to get selected option when using jQuery element variable?

Tags: jquery

I know I can get the value of the selected element like this:

```js
console.log(
    jQuery('.foo select option:selected').val()
);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="foo">
  <select>
    <option>A</option>
    <option>B</option>
    <option selected>C</option>
    <option>D</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

But how does it work if I initialise a variable with the option?
I tried it like this, but no success:

```js
var $option = jQuery('.foo select option');

console.log(
    $option.find("selected").val()
);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="foo">
  <select>
    <option>A</option>
    <option>B</option>
    <option selected>C</option>
    <option>D</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Comment: 1 and 2 both work with  `$(".foo select").val()`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This will [filter](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) out the selected items:

```js
var $option = $(".foo select option");
console.log(
  $option.filter(':selected').val()
);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="foo">
  <select>
    <option>A</option>
    <option>B</option>
    <option selected>C</option>
    <option>D</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

`$option` returns an array of jQuery elements, so you need one extra step to deduce which one of those is selected. In this instance, `find` is looking inside each of the `$option` elements, rather than checking which has the selected attribute.

Comment: No need to filter a select that is not multiple

Comment: @mplungjan, How else to do it with a jQuery variable?

Comment: @mplungjan, no I mean a variable e.g. `$options`

Comment: @Black then this is the answer

Answer (score 2):

Just omit the options from the selector

```
$(".foo select").val()
```

If you must find the option with the selected attribute, just add it to the selector. No need to filter options in a select that is not multiple

```
$(".foo select option[selected]").val()
```

```js
console.log( 
  $(".foo select").val()
);  

// or if you must:

console.log( 
  $(".foo select option[selected]").val()
);  


// Using a variable:

   var $option = $(".foo select option[selected]");
   console.log($option.val())

// another variable

   var $sel = $(".foo select");
   console.log($sel.find("option[selected]").val())
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="foo">
  <select>
    <option>A</option>
    <option>B</option>
    <option selected>C</option>
    <option>D</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Comment: Works, but does not answer the question.

Comment: `No need to make it complicated` yes well that still doesn't answer the question :)

Answer (score 1):

```js
var $option = jQuery('.foo select');

console.log(
    $option.val()
);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="foo">
  <select>
    <option>A</option>
    <option>B</option>
    <option selected>C</option>
    <option>D</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

This way you can do. After the page load no need to check `selected`.
The `selected` attribute is a boolean attribute.

When present, it specifies that an option should be pre-selected when the page loads.

The pre-selected option will be displayed first in the drop-down list.

The `selected` attribute can also be set after the page loads, with a JavaScript.

Comment: @mplungjan Your value selection is different and complicated.

Comment: No it is not: `$(".foo select").val()` - yours is the more verbose version

Comment: No need to check `selected`.

Comment: I am not. In my first DOWNVOTED answer I just had what you have `$(".foo select").val()`

Comment: Your var name is misleading. Your var is the select. I fail to see why this was voted up and mine down

Comment: @mplungjan I am not responsible for that. May be you have some editing from initial answer.